# Codeigniter Show Data from Database into Textbox

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I created an accounts page wherein I can view all accounts from the database. Each of them has an action button called View More. If I press View More, additional details from the database will be displayed in textboxes. I want to get the ID for each of the row and pass it to the controller in order for it to be viewed. However, I can't seem to make them show in the boxes.

Expected: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAwIW.png)

Current: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv1I4.png)

Controller:

```
function viewmore()
{
    $userid = $this->input->get('userid', TRUE);
    $data['view'] = $this->model_accounts->viewmore_user($userid);
    $data['main_content'] = 'view_adminviewmore';
    $this->load->view('includes/admin_viewmore_template', $data);
}
```

Model:

```
public function viewmore_user($userid)
{
     $query= $this->db->select('*')->from('accounts')->where('userid', $userid)->get();
     return $query->result();
}
```

View for the Action Button:

```
          <?php foreach($users as $row): ?>
          <tr>
              <td><?php echo $row->firstname; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row->lastname; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row->username; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row->address; ?></td>
              <td class="action-button mobile-important">
                <a href="<?php echo base_url() ."admin_accounts/viewmore/?id=". $row->userid ?>"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-custom-3">View More</button></a>
              </td>

          <?php endforeach; ?>
          </tr>
```

View for displaying the data:

```
<?php foreach($view as $row): ?>
     <br>
     <p> First Name </p>
     <input class="form-control" id="sel1" type="text" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $row->firstname; ?>">
     <br>
     <p> Last Name </p>
     <input class="form-control" id="sel1" type="text" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $row->lastname; ?>">
     <br>
     <p> Username </p>
     <input class="form-control" id="sel1" type="text" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $row->username; ?>">
     <br>
     <p> Address </p>
     <input class="form-control" id="sel1" type="text" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $row->address; ?>">
     <br>
     <p> E-mail Address </p>
     <input class="form-control" id="sel1" type="email" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $row->email; ?>">
     <br>
     <p> Contact Number </p>
     <input class="form-control" id="sel1" type="text" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $row->contactnum; ?>">
     <br>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CodeIgniter, why not use the Form Helper?

You can use code like this:

```
<?php echo form_input('sel1', $row->firstname); ?>
```

instead of:

```
<input class="form-control" id="sel1" type="text" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $row->firstname; ?>">
```

Read some more about it here: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

your `action button` must be like this:

> you can use `<?="hello word!!!" ?>` instead of `<?php echo "hello word!!!" ?>`
>
> and `base_url()` return the root of your codeigniter folder that set
>   in `application->config->config.php`

```
<a href="<?=base_url()." YOUR_CONTROLLER_NAME/viewmore/".USER_ID ?>View More</a>
```

link above return `<a href="localhost/YOUR_CONTROLLER_NAME/viewmore?id=USER_ID>View More</a>`

and your `function viewmore()` must be change to `function viewmore($id=0)`,this `$id` give USER_ID from your url

and you better to know url in codeigniter contain this:
`Controller`/`Function`/`variable that you want pass to your function`

Comment: Hi, I forgot to add the view for my action button. I edited it above. I already have the ID in my URL, but still I can't display the data in the boxes.

Comment: The image is also above, the one in the current. But I want it to look like the one in the expected.

Comment: but your code is complitly true,you mean `echo $row->firstname;` printed in text box instead of result of it???

Comment: It was just an example, I really want to show the result from the database. I edited it now to avoid confusion. When I remove the foreach loop, the boxes show like the expected. But when I put them back again, the boxes disappear like the current one.

Comment: ok,sure the `foreach` loop create this view for you,for every row that exist in your databse table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132230/discussion-between-coderszx-and-nima).